# Is it possible to log where Firestore reads/writes were made?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm interested in auditing my Firestore activity, it jumped well into the millions unexpectedly today. Debugging it seems to be pretty difficult, I'm curious if there's any sort of logging for which endpoints or collections were hit the most?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no granular auditing for Cloud Firestore.  The only monitoring solution is [available via StackDriver](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/monitor-usage).

Comment: Interesting, similar to the charting provide in Firebase currently, thanks for the link. Would love granular monitoring as a feature request!

Answer (score 0):

Data Access logs may provide what you are looking for, though I haven't personally tried it yet:

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/audit-logging#data-access-audit-logs:-data_read-and-data_write

Note it says:

> Audit logs for the following operations are available as a preview
> offering.